# Using PHP with LDAP returns all results into one connected line

Tags: php, arrays, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get user information from my Active Directory through LDAP. Im using for loops to retrieve each username for a specific AD OU. All results are showing in one line without any separation. If i put 
$LDAP_CN into array it just creates a lot of different arrays.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){

    $LDAP_CN = "";
    if (!empty($entries[$x]['cn'][0])) {
        $LDAP_CN = $entries[$x]['cn'][0];
        if ($LDAP_CN == "NULL"){
            $LDAP_CN = "";
        }
      }
    echo($LDAP_CN);
}
```

output:

```
Name LastnameName1 Lastname1Name2 Lastname2Name3 Lastname3Name4 Lastname4 ant etc.
```

When i try to var_dump $LDAP_CN it gives output like that:

```
string (13) "Name Lastname"
string (15) "Name1 Lastname1"
string (15) "Name2 Lastname2"
string (15) "Name3 Lastname3"
string (15) "Name4 Lastname4"
etc..
```

So i'm guessing that it knows how to separate them. But how ? I tried explode it just creates a lot of arrays.. Also if i put echo out of the loop it just returns last result.

Comment: What your desired output?

Comment: All results in one array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All results in one array:

```
$LDAP_CN = [];
for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){

    if (!empty($entries[$x]['cn'][0])) { 
        $LDAP_CN[] = $entries[$x]['cn'][0] == "NULL" ? "" : $entries[$x]['cn'][0];      
    }
}

print_r($LDAP_CN);
```